# Как определить, стоят ли квадраты в ряд имея координаты их вершин?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Пишу крестики-нолики с произвольным размером игрового поля и количеством клеток в ряд для победы на js.

Класс клетки имеет следующие свойствa

```
this.status = 0; // статус клетки (0 - пустая, название символа - заполненная
this.size = step; // размер клетки
this.cor = {x1: x, y1: y, x2 : x + this.size, y2: y + this.size,x3: x + this.size, y3: y, x4 : x, y4: y + this.size} // координаты вершин клетки
this.centre = {x: x + this.size / 2, y: y + this.size / 2} // координаты центра клетки
```

так же имеется одномерный массив всех клеток

Как узнать стоят ли клетки в ряд?

Comment: Для этого не нужны координаты вершин клетки. Используйте (виртуальные) индексы клетки по горизонтали и вертикали.

Comment: @Igor мб у него в виде одномерного массива хранятся клетки. Впрочем сравнение координаты `y1` даст тот же эффект что и сравнение индекса

Comment: @igor спасибо за совет, я до этого не смог бы догадаться.